# How do I get the text of a button in Java?

Tags: java

```
class Test extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;

    public Test()
    {
        setLayout (new GridLayout (2, 3));

        b1 = new JButton ("Button 1");
        b2 = new JButton ("Button 2");

        add (b1);
        add (b2);
    }

    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getText() == b1.getText())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a method within the `MouseListener` or `JPanel` class that allows me to get the text of a button that is clicked. Thanks

Comment: Use `equals` instead of `==` to compare strings. What's wrong with how you are getting it?

Comment: It says that getText() is not a method in java.awt.event.MouseEvent - is there a similar method in MouseEvent that does return text like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at The [MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) api
There is a method getSource() which you can use that returns the object where the event occurred. Then check if that object is an instance of a button. If it is you can cast it to a button type and then get the text from there.

```
public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event){
   Object o = event.getSource();
   JButton b = null;
   String buttonText = "";

   if(o instanceof JButton)
     b = (JButton)o;

   if(b != null)
     buttonText = b.getText();

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether checking b != null is needed, because null JButton object cannot fire an event, I guess. If I'm wrong, please, correct me.

Comment: @Benjamin needed f.e. get JBUtton from Model, or AbstractButton both +1

Comment: @Benjamin The null check is there specifically for the case of the mousePressed being used for different components. Other components could be using this method to act as a controller for mouse events. That would be up to the developer to decide. you could also keep everything in the original instanceof if statement if you wish. I just wrote it out for simplicity.

Comment: I wouldn't fully agree with this logical flow. If you make the if statement check if `o` is **not** an instance of `JButton`, not only does that tighten up the logic, but also makes the null check redundant and gets rid of the `b` variable completely.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `MouseListener` with a `JButton`. You should edit your answer to also recommend `ActionListener`. This Q&A has almost 9,000 views. People read it.

Answer (score 5):

You should try looking at ActionListener and implement it. Those Actions are fired, whenever you click a button, this is how you should work:

```
class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
...
   public Test() {
        super();
        ...
        b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        ...
        add(b1);
        ...
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(((JButton) event.getSource()).getText());
        if (event.getSource() == b1) {
            // do sth
        } else if (event.getSource() == b2) {
            // do sth else
        }
    }
}
```

Then write a main method and add a new instance of `Test` panel to a `JFrame` and see how it works.

Tutorial can be found on the following website:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts too...  and here's the answer:   there is no .getText() method for a Button... you want to use .getLabel()
Aren't namespaces fun?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

//********************************************************

        String Hunt1 = evt.toString();
        Hunt1 = Hunt1.replaceAll("=", ",");
        Hunt1 = Hunt1.replaceAll("]", ",");
        String [] Hunt2 = Hunt1.split(",");
        List Hunt3 = Arrays.asList(Hunt2);
        String ButtonText = Hunt3.get(2).toString();
        System.out.println(ButtonText); }

//*******************************************************
```

This is how I did it. I was looking for a way to pass button names out to a method so that I could run down an `if(s==Button1){}else if(s==Button2){.....` scope of about 12 buttons.

Catching a button name proved difficult for me (I have only been doing Java for a day or so) so I came up with this to pass the label/text out to a method.

That code can be placed in its own method so that after you make your button set you can just go into each click event and paste

```
SendButtonLabel(evt.ToString());
```

then pass it from there to your if/then buttonlist method

or whatever your project needs without having to actually go in and hardcode anything into each click event. I suppose that it would be possible if you were doing a particular project to set up your IDE to auto-add that method call to each click event as it is created, but I am not that far advanced as of yet.