# how to get button text value in java

Tags: java, button

I want to get button text value to do the on click command, but i can't find the right code to do it. I think I need a code to replace the //button text value// on the code showed below.

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(420,420);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("1");

        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button {
            if(//button text value// == 1) {
                button.setText("3");
            }
            if(//button text value// == 1) {
                button.setText("2");
            }
    
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the text of a button in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029162/how-do-i-get-the-text-of-a-button-in-java)

Comment: Did you not search the documentation? The superclass of `JButton` (i.e. `AbstractButton`) has a [getText](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getText()) method. Is that not what you need?

Comment: Note that `getText()` will return a `String`, which you cannot compare to an integer with `... == 1`. You would have to compare it as a string instead: `button.getText().equals("1")`

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't contain and proper idea one what should happen when the button is pressed so I decided to increment it up to 3 each time.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new Main());
    }
    Main() {
        button.setText("1");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(button.getText().equals("1")) {
                    button.setText("2");
                }
                else if(button.getText().equals("2")) {
                    button.setText("3");
                }
                else if(button.getText().equals("3")) {
                    button.setText("1");
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

First of all, your `actionPerformed` was unable to use the JButton because it was declared as a local variable in your main method.

In a short summary on what this code does, it sets the value of the button to 1, and adds an `ActionListener` (Remember that you dont have to check if `e.getSource()==button`  because this will only run if the button is pressed) which gets the text and increments it (resets it to one if the value is 3) and then you basically add this button to a JFrame.